# Fuse Osgi Bundle Monitoring

Tags: osgi-bundle, jbossfuse, hawtio

Wondering how you guys monitor osgi bundles deployed on your Fuse Container. Ideally looking for something which is able to notify by email if some bundle has gone down and needs addressing.  HawtIO i guess can do a job but has no "notify" capability as far as i know. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuse has a number of entry points that exposes the data you are looking for.

- You can use JMX to connect to the container and ask for the bundles
  and their status.
- You can use Jolokia whic exposes all the JMX data
  over http.
- You write some bash script and use Fuse CLI to access
  bundle information. (for example: ./client list | grep -i failure)

So which of the above methods you are going to use, depends on your monitoring tool. But usually monitoring tools will let you write some bash/python scripts and using these scripts you can access the data you need.

I've used Nagios/OPSView/JON as monitoring/alerting tool, and it works great.

Here is blog post from a colleague of mine demonstrating how to monitor Fuse using Nagios:

http://giallone.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/monitoring-jboss-fuse-esb-with-nagios.html

Enjoy!

Comment: The blog post of your colleague is really good and I enjoyed reading it. I recommend it for everyone who wants to have a first insight by example in _Fuse OSGi Bundle Monitoring_.